# crystal report move table to next page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I am using c# crystal report,i have some text in header section below comes is a table in sub-report below table is footer section,if table rows grows in size,end rows get cutoff,what i want to do is if table rows grew in size it should get display in next page and below that footer section should be display.
Do anyone knows how to achieved it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to give Can Grow option for the fields inside the sub report and also
give the same option for the sub report too

FYI, Can Grow option is available in the context menu which can be accessed by right clicking on the sub report and choose the format report option

Comment: thanks for kind help,eventually i made it by placing subreport inside detail section rather than header section and enabling can grow check box.